# Square of two enumeration for use with logic operators in flags

Tags: java, enums, flags

So, I have this enum:

```
public enum Loglevel {
    ERROR, WARNING, NOTICE, VERBOSE, INFO;
}
```

And I would like to have such class:

```
public class Log {
    public statoc Loglevel level = Loglevel.ERROR | Loglevel.WARNING | Loglevel.NOTICE | Loglevel.VERBOSE | Loglevel.INFO;
    public static void log(String message, Loglevel lvl) {
        if(level & lvl) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
}
```

Of course,  understand that `Loglevel.ERROR | Loglevel.WARNING` is an error, but I need something similar - and I'm quite new to all the special approaches that java uses.

If nothing else, I can, of course go like this:

```
public class Loglevel {
    public static final int ERROR = 1;
    public static final int WARNING = 2;
    public static final int NOTICE = 4;
}
```

But I think there might be a smarter solution to this.

Comment: You can use the `ordinal()` of the enums but that becomes very wordy. I would just use the `int` (you're missing the type) solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to "compare" a `LogLevel` against another to see if it's high enough a log level to get logged.  Using flags to represent bits and using bitwise math to access them isn't a good idea here, because there isn't a possibility of different combinations of flags to be set independently, i.e. it can't be both `ERROR` and `WARNING` at the same time.

I would take your enum and add an integer `level` to it, and assign different numbers to each `Loglevel`.  Then, when deciding whether to log a message, you can compare the message's `Loglevel` to the current `Loglevel` to determine whether it's high enough to log.

Comment: Yeah, one message can't indeed be both ERROR and WARNING. But the current loglevel filter can be any combination of the log entry types.
For example, you might want to see all ERROR and INFO, but ignore warnings and notices.